# How to change orientation of iOS map while the user moves?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I’ve been checking on the internet and could not find the solution to my problem, even it seems a really simple thing.

I’m implementing a simple iOS app that tracks the user location in a map, by using Mapkit framework.

Everything is fine, but I cannot find how to make the map automatically rotate while user moves. I want the map to point to the user direction instead of pointing to the north, as it does in the iOS Maps application after calibrating process.

Any idea will be very very very appreciated, because I feel a bit lost. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [`userTrackingMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/userTrackingMode) property on `MKMapView`. As the docs note, `FollowWithHeading` is the one that rotates the map.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer!! but I already have this property set to MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading and it does'nt work. Think it just sets the center to user location but it does'nt rotate the whole map...

Comment: Oh sorry, rickster, you were right. MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading follows and rotates according to user direction. I'll check what happens in my app because it should work...